# If processes can't modify their parent's environment, what is MC doing?

Tags: process, environment-variables, pwd

As far as I know, a process cannot modify its parent's environment. However, when I run `mc` (GNU's Midnight Commander, a curses-based file manager) and then quit it, I end up with another `$PWD`:

```
[localhost ~]$ echo $PWD
/home/pedro
[localhost ~]$ mc

removed `/tmp/mc-pedro/mc.pwd.5616'
[localhost pedro]$ echo $PWD
/nfs/home/pedro
```

I know that it hasn't really "changed", because `/home` is a symlink to `/nfs/home`, but anyway, `$PWD` was a string, and now it's a different string.

What's happening here?

Comment: What do you get from `type mc` on bash?

Comment: @yaegashi nailed it. `type mc` gives `mc is aliased to \`. /usr/libexec/mc/mc-wrapper.sh'`, and the pwd is changed from inside `mc-wrapper.sh` (actually, that's pretty much the only thing this annoying script does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `mc` command is aliased to `. /some/script` the script is executed in the *current* environment (`.` is equivalent to `source` in some shells).

A script that is executed in this way may well change the environment of the calling shell, since it's executing in the same environment.

Comment: Note that `.` is the standard command. In some shells like `bash` and `ksh93` that have a `source` command, both `.` and `source` are not strictly equivalent. In ksh, `source` is an alias for `command .` (so `.` with the special attributes removed).